# How to combine multi-index column values on condition using numpy broadcasting

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have a problem that I am 99% sure has a numpy broadcasting solution, but I'm unable to figure it out. Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
iterables = [['US', 'DE'], ['A', 'B'], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
idx3 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables, names=['v1', 'v2', 'v3'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randn(20,2), index=idx3)
print(d3)
                c1        c2
v1 v2 v3                    
US A  1  -0.023208 -1.047208
      2   1.128917  0.292252
      3  -0.441574  0.038714
      4   1.057893  1.313874
      5   0.938736 -0.130192
   B  1  -0.479439 -0.311465
      2  -1.730325 -1.300829
      3  -0.112920 -0.269385
      4   1.436866  0.197434
      5   1.659529  2.107746
DE A  1   0.533169 -0.539891
      2   0.225635  1.406626
      3  -0.928966  0.979749
      4  -0.109132  0.862450
      5  -0.481120  1.425678
   B  1   0.592646 -0.573862
      2  -1.135009 -0.365472
      3   0.728357  0.744631
      4   0.156970  0.623244
      5  -0.071628 -0.089194
```

Now suppose I want column c3, such that c3 is equal to column c1 for values 1-3 of index-level v3, and is equal to column c2 for values 3-5 of index-level v3.

Using apply this ought to be easy.

```
df3.reset_index('v3').apply(lambda df: df.c1 if df.v3<=3 else df.c2, axis=1)
```

But this is looping through each row and checking a condition. 
Using boolean indexing I can get here:

```
bool1 = df3.loc[df3.index.get_level_values('v3')<=3,['c1']]
bool2 = df3.loc[df3.index.get_level_values('v3')>3,['c2']]

print bool1
                c1
v1 v2 v3          
US A  1  -0.023208
      2   1.128917
      3  -0.441574
   B  1  -0.479439
      2  -1.730325
      3  -0.112920
DE A  1   0.533169
      2   0.225635
      3  -0.928966
   B  1   0.592646
      2  -1.135009
      3   0.728357

print bool2
                c2
v1 v2 v3          
US A  4   1.313874
      5  -0.130192
   B  4   0.197434
      5   2.107746
DE A  4   0.862450
      5   1.425678
   B  4   0.623244
      5  -0.089194
```

But can't figure out how to get this back in my original dataframe. I feel like I'm basically there, but keep running down dead ends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Base on your code

```
df3['c3']=pd.concat([bool1.rename(columns={'c1':'c3'}),bool2.rename(columns={'c2':'c3'})])
```

---

***And this is what we usually do*** `np.where`

```
df3['c3']=np.where(df3.index.get_level_values('v3')<3,df3.c1,df3.c2)
df3
Out[1124]: 
                c1        c2        c3
v1 v2 v3                              
US A  1   0.141297  0.304322  0.141297
      2  -0.532937  0.599611 -0.532937
      3   0.480130 -0.601851 -0.601851
      4  -0.208570  0.428122  0.428122
      5  -0.775055 -1.842595 -1.842595
   B  1  -0.985807 -0.259167 -0.985807
      2  -0.211140  0.514273 -0.211140
      3   0.006876  0.261158  0.261158
      4  -1.001227  0.069682  0.069682
      5  -0.937359 -0.364904 -0.364904
DE A  1  -0.510380 -1.815965 -0.510380
      2   0.730677  1.901079  0.730677
      3  -0.439140  1.068193  1.068193
      4   0.183268  1.879705  1.879705
      5  -1.455026  0.958647  0.958647
   B  1   1.491328  2.139492  1.491328
      2  -0.035495  1.487377 -0.035495
      3  -0.503681  0.837837  0.837837
      4  -2.320546  0.683476  0.683476
      5  -2.407492  0.962752  0.962752
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`Series.where()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html) function to do this efficiently. For example:

```
>>> df = df3.reset_index('v3')
>>> df['c3'] = df['c1'].where(df['v3'] <= 3, df['c2'])
>>> df
       v3        c1        c2        c3
v1 v2                                  
US A    1  0.220979 -1.361330  0.220979
   A    2 -0.902486  0.931644 -0.902486
   A    3 -0.324257  0.582866 -0.324257
   A    4  0.130595  0.809319  0.809319
   A    5 -1.432045 -1.299859 -1.299859
   B    1 -0.221528 -1.171605 -0.221528
   B    2 -0.025748 -0.244276 -0.025748
   B    3 -0.842640 -0.381956 -0.842640
   B    4  3.051674  0.675167  0.675167
   B    5 -0.232921 -0.553047 -0.553047
DE A    1  0.011917  0.528074  0.011917
   A    2  0.793363 -1.037817  0.793363
   A    3 -0.647931  0.458625 -0.647931
   A    4  0.675414  0.775137  0.775137
   A    5  0.648263  0.462900  0.462900
   B    1 -0.040314  1.427158 -0.040314
   B    2 -1.354950  0.807179 -1.354950
   B    3 -1.051297 -0.671725 -1.051297
   B    4  0.305435 -0.482608 -0.482608
   B    5  1.788918  0.527372  0.527372
```

Answer (score 2):

**Option 0**
`pd.Series.mask` and `pd.DataFrame.eval`

```
df3.assign(c3=df3.c1.mask(df3.eval('v3 > 3'), df3.c2))

                c1        c2        c3
v1 v2 v3                              
US A  1  -0.725168  0.267357 -0.725168
      2   0.737184 -0.675266  0.737184
      3   0.860002  1.158949  0.860002
      4  -0.243702 -0.036094 -0.036094
      5  -0.700788  0.042080  0.042080
   B  1   0.955489  0.207721  0.955489
      2   1.167202 -1.132584  1.167202
      3   1.937948 -1.476343  1.937948
      4   0.385508  0.731786  0.731786
      5  -1.356454 -1.815996 -1.815996
DE A  1  -0.164354 -1.354613 -0.164354
      2  -0.264868  0.182453 -0.264868
      3   1.768679  0.568956  1.768679
      4  -1.790169 -0.298174 -0.298174
      5  -1.242662  1.445414  1.445414
   B  1  -0.081639 -0.464066 -0.081639
      2   0.071672  0.409464  0.071672
      3  -0.770912 -0.432803 -0.770912
      4  -1.616662 -0.642879 -0.642879
      5  -0.815786  0.991889  0.991889
```

---

**Option 1**
`pd.DataFrame.query` and `pd.Series.append`

```
df3.assign(c3=df3.query('v3 in [1, 2, 3]').c1.append(df3.query('v3 in [4, 5]').c2))

                c1        c2        c3
v1 v2 v3                              
US A  1  -0.725168  0.267357 -0.725168
      2   0.737184 -0.675266  0.737184
      3   0.860002  1.158949  0.860002
      4  -0.243702 -0.036094 -0.036094
      5  -0.700788  0.042080  0.042080
   B  1   0.955489  0.207721  0.955489
      2   1.167202 -1.132584  1.167202
      3   1.937948 -1.476343  1.937948
      4   0.385508  0.731786  0.731786
      5  -1.356454 -1.815996 -1.815996
DE A  1  -0.164354 -1.354613 -0.164354
      2  -0.264868  0.182453 -0.264868
      3   1.768679  0.568956  1.768679
      4  -1.790169 -0.298174 -0.298174
      5  -1.242662  1.445414  1.445414
   B  1  -0.081639 -0.464066 -0.081639
      2   0.071672  0.409464  0.071672
      3  -0.770912 -0.432803 -0.770912
      4  -1.616662 -0.642879 -0.642879
      5  -0.815786  0.991889  0.991889
```

---

**Option 2**
`pd.IndexSlice`

```
i1 = pd.IndexSlice[:, :, 1:3]
i2 = pd.IndexSlice[:, :, 4:5]
h = lambda d: d.loc[i1, 'c1'].append(d.loc[i2, 'c2'])

df3.assign(c3=df3.sort_index().pipe(h))

                c1        c2        c3
v1 v2 v3                              
US A  1  -0.725168  0.267357 -0.725168
      2   0.737184 -0.675266  0.737184
      3   0.860002  1.158949  0.860002
      4  -0.243702 -0.036094 -0.036094
      5  -0.700788  0.042080  0.042080
   B  1   0.955489  0.207721  0.955489
      2   1.167202 -1.132584  1.167202
      3   1.937948 -1.476343  1.937948
      4   0.385508  0.731786  0.731786
      5  -1.356454 -1.815996 -1.815996
DE A  1  -0.164354 -1.354613 -0.164354
      2  -0.264868  0.182453 -0.264868
      3   1.768679  0.568956  1.768679
      4  -1.790169 -0.298174 -0.298174
      5  -1.242662  1.445414  1.445414
   B  1  -0.081639 -0.464066 -0.081639
      2   0.071672  0.409464  0.071672
      3  -0.770912 -0.432803 -0.770912
      4  -1.616662 -0.642879 -0.642879
      5  -0.815786  0.991889  0.991889
```

---

**Option 3**
Tricky `pd.DataFrame.eval` and numpy slicing

```
df3.assign(c3=df3.values[np.arange(len(df3)), df3.eval('v3').gt(3).astype(int)])

                c1        c2        c3
v1 v2 v3                              
US A  1  -0.725168  0.267357 -0.725168
      2   0.737184 -0.675266  0.737184
      3   0.860002  1.158949  0.860002
      4  -0.243702 -0.036094 -0.036094
      5  -0.700788  0.042080  0.042080
   B  1   0.955489  0.207721  0.955489
      2   1.167202 -1.132584  1.167202
      3   1.937948 -1.476343  1.937948
      4   0.385508  0.731786  0.731786
      5  -1.356454 -1.815996 -1.815996
DE A  1  -0.164354 -1.354613 -0.164354
      2  -0.264868  0.182453 -0.264868
      3   1.768679  0.568956  1.768679
      4  -1.790169 -0.298174 -0.298174
      5  -1.242662  1.445414  1.445414
   B  1  -0.081639 -0.464066 -0.081639
      2   0.071672  0.409464  0.071672
      3  -0.770912 -0.432803 -0.770912
      4  -1.616662 -0.642879 -0.642879
      5  -0.815786  0.991889  0.991889
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a NumPy way to leverage `broadcasting` -

```
# Get index level and the indices
l = df3.index.names.index('v3')
i = np.array(df3.index.levels[l])

# Get array data
a = df3.values.reshape(-1,len(i),2)

# Finally use np.where to choose between the two cols based on indices
df3['c3'] = (np.where(i <= 3,a[:,:,0],a[:,:,1])).ravel()
```

**Runtime test**

Approaches -

```
def reset_where_app(df3): # @jakevdp's soln
    df = df3.reset_index('v3')
    df['c3'] = df['c1'].where(df['v3'] <= 3, df['c2'])
    return df

def concat_app(df3): # @Wen's soln
    bool1 = df3.loc[df3.index.get_level_values('v3')<=3,['c1']]
    bool2 = df3.loc[df3.index.get_level_values('v3')>3,['c2']]
    df3['c3']=pd.concat([bool1.rename(columns={'c1':'c3'}),\
              bool2.rename(columns={'c2':'c3'})])
    return df3    

def assign_app(df3):      # @piRSquared's soln-1
    return df3.assign(c3=df3.c1.mask(df3.eval('v3 > 3'), df3.c2))    

def indexslice_app(df3): # @piRSquared's soln-2
    i1 = pd.IndexSlice[:, :, 1:3]
    i2 = pd.IndexSlice[:, :, 4:5]
    h = lambda d: d.loc[i1, 'c1'].append(d.loc[i2, 'c2'])    
    return df3.assign(c3=df3.sort_index().pipe(h))

def assigneval_app(df3): # @piRSquared's soln-3
    return df3.assign(c3=df3.values[np.arange(len(df3)),\
    df3.eval('v3').gt(3).astype(int)])

def numpy_app(df3):
    l = df3.index.names.index('v3')
    i = np.array(df3.index.levels[l])
    a = df3.values.reshape(-1,len(i),2)
    df3['c3'] = (np.where(i <= 3,a[:,:,0],a[:,:,1])).ravel()
    return df3
```

Timings on sample data posted in question -

```
In [256]: iterables = [['US', 'DE'], ['A', 'B'], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
     ...: idx3 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables, names=['v1', 'v2', 'v3'])
     ...: df3 = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randn(20,2), index=idx3)
     ...: df3.columns = [['c1','c2']]

In [257]: %timeit reset_where_app(df3.copy())
     ...: %timeit concat_app(df3.copy())
     ...: %timeit assign_app(df3.copy())
     ...: %timeit indexslice_app(df3.copy())
     ...: %timeit assigneval_app(df3.copy())
     ...: %timeit numpy_app(df3.copy())
100 loops, best of 3: 1.87 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 3.97 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 2.77 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 3.92 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.43 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 314 µs per loop
```

Timings on a bigger dataset (100 x 100 x 100 data with 2 cols) -

```
In [258]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: n = 100
     ...: r = range(1,n+1)
     ...: l = len(r)
     ...: iterables = [r,r,r]
     ...: pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables, names=['v1', 'v2', 'v3'])
     ...: idx3 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables, names=['v1', 'v2', 'v3'])
     ...: df3 = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randn(l*l*l,2), index=idx3)
     ...: df3.columns = [['c1','c2']]

In [259]: %timeit reset_where_app(df3.copy())
     ...: %timeit concat_app(df3.copy())
     ...: %timeit assign_app(df3.copy())
     ...: %timeit indexslice_app(df3.copy())
     ...: %timeit assigneval_app(df3.copy())
     ...: %timeit numpy_app(df3.copy())
10 loops, best of 3: 42.6 ms per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 318 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 62.2 ms per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 725 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 27.2 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 6 ms per loop
```